# Need help creating a Java Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have a requirement where I have to modify the annotation

```
@Qualifier(CONSTANT + "ABC")
DataSource dataSource;
```

to

```
@DataSourceQualifier("ABC")
DataSource dataSource;
```

Here is my Annotation code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface DataSourceQualifier {
    String value();
}
```

Is it even possible to do this? I have previously used annotation with AOP but I do not understand how to create this decorator annotation.

Comment: Since there is no inheritance model for interfaces, and no method implementations, I think that what you want (prefixing) is not possible. This would normally be something that is done on the annotation's consumer.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no `value` involved, then it would be possible assuming `Qualifier` annotation is annotated with `@Inherited`, then you could annotate your `DataSourceQualifier` with the `@Qualifier`, then all the places that you annotate with `@DataSourceQualifier` for the purpose of annotation processing would act as if they had the `@Qualifier` annotation.

However, if you want to do any passing of a your annotation's value into the metaannotation value, that's not possible.

Comment: You can pass the value into the meta annotation using the `@AliasFor` in Spring, so yes you can do that.